# Unable to mount local host directory into docker volume in redhat linux

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-volume

I am able to create docker volume using below command.

```
docker volume create test
```

However when I tried to mount the local directory with docker volume using below command

```
docker volume create --driver local --opt type=nfs --opt o=addr=<ip address>,rw --opt device=:<local host directory> rk-files
```

getting error as below.

> Error response from daemon: access denied:
>   no access to Volume Create/Attach with [Local Driver Options], on collection 52f65fa2-b201-4b24-bf1e-b4948a90e3d0

Can someone help me to solve this issue.

Comment: I assume that you have the rights to access that NFS location, right? Because it looks like you don't have the rights to do so

Comment: yes I have rights to that location, actually i created local NFS share path on the linux VM where I am executing the above command.